# Schengen Visa "member state of first entry"

Tags: schengen-visas, iceland

I am filling in the Harmonised application form and at point 26, there is a field called **Member state of the first country**.

I have my flight booked from India to Iceland via the Netherlands, where I will be changing my flights at Schiphol, Amsterdam.

As per the official website here:

https://www.netherlandsworldwide.nl/transiting-airport-netherlands/international-transit-zone-schiphol

It says:

> You leave the international transit zone and enter the Netherlands
> when you go through passport control.
>
> You must always leave the international transit zone:
>
> - to transfer from an intercontinental flight to a European flight.
>   This
>   means: you have flown to the Netherlands from a country outside the
>   Schengen area and are transferring to an onward flight within the
>   Schengen area

My questions:

1. For section (26), should I fill in **Netherlands** instead of **Iceland**?
2. For section (27), **Number of entries requested**, should I request for 2 or Multiple entries as I will be entering 2 Schengen areas?

Comment: There is only **one** Schengen Area with (presently) 27 member countries. You will be visiting 2 of those countries. Only if you leave the Schengen Area during your planned trip (i.e. to visit Ireland or the United Kingdom, which are **not** Schengen countries) and then return to the Schengen Area would you require more than one entry.

Comment: Note that if you transit via the UK or Ireland, even if you don’t enter that country, that will still count and an exit from Schengen followed by a new entry into Schengen. This would require a dual or multiple entry visa. If you fly directly from the Netherlands to Iceland (and then back) a single entry is enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will enter the Schengen area once, in the Netherlands. Then you will take an *internal* flight to Iceland.

25. Destination is Iceland
26. First Entry is the Netherlands
27. Number of Entries is 1, date of entry is when you arrive in the Netherlands (not in Iceland), date of exit is the last day in any Schengen state.

Basically you are telling them that Iceland is the one processing your application, and the Netherlands is where you will come and present your visa.